# Representing Graph in EF Code-First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am trying to represent a graph with typed edges in an entity-framework code-first model.  I am having quite a difficulty understanding how to set up the relationships correctly.  I am calling the nodes in my graph 'Items' and the edges 'Relationships'  Here is what I have:

```
public class Item : Learnable
{
    public Boolean IsBeginningItem { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Relationship> RelationshipsLeft { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Relationship> RelationshipsRight { get; set; }
}
```

-

```
public class Relationship : Learnable
{
    public Boolean IsPrerequisiteRelationship { get; set; }
    public virtual RelationshipType RelationshipType { get; set; }

    public int ItemLeftID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemLeftID")]
    public virtual Item ItemLeft { get; set; }

    public int ItemRightID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemRightID")]
    public virtual Item ItemRight { get; set; }
}
```

And here is what I am getting:

[image]

How can I get the RelationshipsRight property of Item to correspond to the ItemLeft property of Relationship AND the RelationshipsLeft property of Item to correspond to the ItemRight property of Relationship?

Oh... and I guess I should explain that this is supposed to be a directed graph that I can navigate bidirectionally. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[InverseProperty]` attribute to bind the correct pairs of navigation properties together:

```
public class Relationship
{
    //...

    public int ItemLeftID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemLeftID"), InverseProperty("RelationshipsRight")]
    public virtual Item ItemLeft { get; set; }

    public int ItemRightID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemRightID"), InverseProperty("RelationshipsLeft")]
    public virtual Item ItemRight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that simple, huh?  Thank you so much, it worked perfectly!